# Is it possible to implement Active Active multi-instance queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

while I am studying multi-instance queue manager, all the docs talk about active standby queue manager and only two instances of the queue manager one active and another standby, and standby monitors the active instance. the question is, is it possible to configure an active-active multi-instance (more than two instances) queue manager?

Comment: No it is not possible.   A single queue manger instance can only be live on one server at any given time.   You could have a second queue manger  that is active on a different server but they are not the same instance.  For example QMGR1 and QMGR2.

Comment: what is the limitation that makes it impossible to have a QMGR1 active in both two instances at the same time?

Comment: It can only be active on one server,  that's how it works.